# File upload to the asp.net web service not working

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, web-services, file-upload

I'm trying to upload file to the web service using JavaScript and JQuery. My current implementation is working correctly in the local environment.
But after deploying my solution to the server and try to access from outside it's not working and saying server side error occurred. Other thing I found is other web methods of the same web service are working correctly and just this file upload method is not working.

Here is my asp.net web service file upload method.

```
 [WebMethod]
 [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
 public object SaveFile()
 {
     var bugID = int.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["bugID"]);
     var fileName = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["name"];
     var fileType = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["type"];
     var file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0];

     // file saving logic
     // .....

     return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
     {
         Message = 1,
         Name = fileName,
         DocumentID = attach.DocumentID // Saved file ID
     });
 }
```

Here is the javascript method I used to upload the file to the web service

```
function uploadFile() {
    var data = new FormData(),
    file = $("#fileToUpload")[0].files[0];

    data.append("name", file.name);
    data.append("size", file.size);
    data.append("type", file.type);
    data.append("file", file);
    data.append("bugID", bugID);

    $.ajax(
    {
        url: baseURL + "Webservice/BugsWebService.asmx/SaveFile",
        dataType: "xml",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (res) {
            console.log(res);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

In development environment web service url is

> http://localhost:55225/Bugs/View.aspx

When host the site url is

> http://[ip-address]/Internal/Bugs/View.aspx

This is the error I'm getting when try to upload the file

```
http://[ip-address]/Internal/Webservice/BugsWebService.asmx/SaveFile
```

500 (Internal Server Error)

What is the issue with my implementation?

Comment: Have you tried accessing the web service URL from the web browser after hosting it? Try fiddler or another client side tool to access the web-service to narrow down the problem.

Comment: `var data = new FormData(),` <-- comma

Comment: I can access the webservice from the web browser and other functions are working correctly in that web service. This issue happens only for file upload function.